# Generating maximum profit while calculating cart

Tags: algorithms, percentages

I have a question related to Business Model.

Let's say I have an $x$ number of products with fixed cost. The cost of products
can range from low to high. I also have the purchase amount for those products and listing
amount for those products i.e the selling price of those products.

I want to calculate a cart such that I always gain a certain unit money on that cart
or a certain percentage of the total amount on that cart. I can add an amount $y$ to the cart in order to change the final profit amount.

How do I approach this solution? Also calculating with fixed unit money is a good idea
or calculating with fixed percentage?

Answer (score 0):

You can do either, because $x+y + P(x+y) > x+y$ assuming $P$ is a positive percentage, and $x+y+z > x+y$, assuming $z$ is a positive number.

$P$ is a percentage to add to the cart, and $z$ is a fixed vaule.